# Error 'No application is open' RobotFramework Mobile test script execution on saucelabs

Tags: android, mobile, appium, robotframework, saucelabs

I'm trying to run the robot framework mobile test script using appiumlibrary on saucelabs. I am getting the following error 'no application is open'.

Here is my code

```
Open Application  https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub
    ...  appiumVersion=1.18.1
    ...  platformName=Android
    ...  platformVersion=8.0
    ...  browserName=Chrome
    ...  deviceName=Samsung Galaxy S7
    ...  username=xxxxx
    ...  accessKey=xxxxx
    ...  appPackage=com.android.chrome
    ...  appActivity=org.chromium.chrome.browser.document.ChromeLauncherActivity
    ...  automationName=Uiautomator2
```

Is something wrong with my code or is there any settings/configuration on sauce labs that needs to be set?

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks ok based on how the `Open Application` library works. Two possible issues:

- You need to include an `app` capability in your list above to target an application on Sauce Labs. Make sure you include this and that the app is uploaded to Sauce.
- You may need to update the first argument to use a [specific Sauce data center endpoint](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Data+Center+Endpoints#DataCenterEndpoints-USDataCenter). Also make sure the application you uploaded to test against is in the correct data center.

Here's an [example of using RobotFramework with Sauce](https://github.com/saucelabs-training/demo-python/blob/master/examples/robotframework/native_mobile/android/tests/resource.robot) to test a native mobile application.

Comment: I am not trying to run the tests on a mobile app using the apk file uploaded to sauce. I am trying to launch the chrome browser on mobile device present in sauce labs and test a web application. Is there any example document/code for this scenario?

Comment: Try removing the `appPackage` and `appActivity` capabilities, maybe the `automationName` as well.